# get a String and put a standart text before

Tags: java, android, facebook

I would like to set a general text, and after the text, there should be an individual number, like so: *can you beat my score? (X.XX sec)*

I've tried this:

```
       FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
.setLink("www.facebook.com/FrozenSparks.ch")
    .setName(.setText("Can you beat my score?"))(prefs.getString("thetime1", "-")))
    .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

    }
```

, but this gives me just a couple of errors.

Comment: on what are you calling `.setText`??

Comment: aah...nothing I see.. but what else do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
.setName("Can you beat my score?" + prefs.getString("thetime1", "-"))
```

There seem to be a number of erroneous parentheses/braces in your code sample, I hope that's only a copy and paste mistake.

Comment: Sir, let me thank you for this great help. here, take my acceptance